# Spree + TinyMCE + Change o2k theme to something else created a trouble for editing the content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce, spree

In Spree, I am trying to change the skin of TinyMCE from o2k theme to something.

By changing the tinymce.yml =>

```
skin : "o2k"
```

to

```
skin : "default"
```

Here in picture, you can see while typing the contents, the whole text comes in between of the editor.

[image]

And while editing the content, only editor is there but content is missing.

[image]

I did not get the way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle, I found one of my blunder work ie using by using hide property, I am trying to hide some options of TinyMCE.

Coincidently, due to changes in yml file ordering of tables get changed and context div get hide. Now the problem is resolved.

```
So please check the order of the DIV if you encountered with such issue.
```